# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. ts error exists even when using any

Tags: typescript, vue.js

[image]

```
let index = selectedActivities.value.indexOf(activity_id);
```

I am getting ts error , Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. how do i resolve this

Comment: What are the types of `selectedActivities.value` and `props.importData`?

Comment: @NicholasTower activity_id is string.

Comment: And `selectedActivities.value`? It looks like it's a `never[]`. Please show us the type so we can tell you how to fix the type.

Comment: @NicholasTower is a array. const selectedActivities = ref([]); defined like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const selectedActivities = ref([]);
```

Since you havn't given this a type, typescript has to infer it. It sees you passed in an array, but has no idea what should be inside that array, so it gives it the type `never[]`. Trying to check a `never[]` for a string does not work, because it doesn't contain strings.

Instead, you need to specify what type of array this is:

```
const selectedActivities = ref<string[]>([]);
```

Or:

```
const selectedActivities = ref([] as string[]);
```

Comment: this solved the issue, thankyou for spending your time to help me